# Spark dataframe convert string to timestamp - returns null for empty value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark app, that need to convert from string to timestamp below is my code.

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq("09/18/2017","")).toDF("sDate")
+----------+
|     sDate|
+----------+
|09/18/2017|
|          |
+----------+
val ts = unix_timestamp($"sDate","MM/dd/yyyy").cast("timestamp")
df.withColumn("ts", ts).show()
+----------+--------------------+
|     sDate|                  ts|
+----------+--------------------+
|09/18/2017|2017-09-18 00:00:...|
|          |                null|
+----------+--------------------+
```

The conversion is doing good, but if the value is empty , I'm getting null after casting.

Is there any way to return empty if the source value is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `when` function as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val ts = unix_timestamp($"sDate","MM/dd/yyyy").cast("timestamp")
df.withColumn("ts", when(ts.isNotNull, ts).otherwise(lit("empty"))).show()
```

which would give you output as

```
+----------+-------------------+
|     sDate|                 ts|
+----------+-------------------+
|09/18/2017|2017-09-18 00:00:00|
|          |              empty|
+----------+-------------------+
```